# How to send all byte into single array and later xor between the bytes?

Tags: java, arrays

I have socket application and I can read byte by byte and I need push all the byte into one single array.
I read like below.So I will have 12+bodylen bytes.

```
int messageID = r.readUnsignedShort();
int bodyLen = r.readUnsignedShort();       
byte[] phoneNum = new byte[6];
r.readFully(phoneNum);  
int serialNum = r.readUnsignedShort();     
byte[] messageBody = new byte[bodyLen];    
r.readFully(messageBody);
byte checkCode = r.readByte();
```

My challenge is how to push all the byte into one fullMessage and there after I need to xor between each of this bytes and get the results as byte too.

```
byte[] fullMessage = new byte[12+bodyLen];
```

Comment: What is `r`? stream/data reader ?

Comment: r is  r = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(receivedSocketConn1.getInputStream()));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dont need to have everything in separate and you need all in single array, after reading `bodyLen` you can do something like this:

```
int messageID = r.readUnsignedShort();
int bodyLen = r.readUnsignedShort();       
byte[] fullMessage=new byte[12+bodyLen];
r.readFully(fullMessage,0,fullMessage.length);
```

Here `fullMessage` will contain all the data you are reading step by step in your code in single array.

**But if you need all the parts to be read separately: read below**

To concatenate arrays and other elements into array use [ByteBuffer#put(byte[])](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#put(byte[])). 
After work is done, get the array from buffer using `.array()` method of `ByteBuffer`

`byte[] fullMessage=byteBuffer.array();`

Later on, iterate over array and do required work

```
for(int i=0,s=fullMessage.lengthl;i<s;i++){
     // do your XOR operations -> xor operator is ^
}
```

Comment: No I dont need the the full cause few byte at the front and end I need to ignore ?

Comment: How to add each of the reading of the byte into the fullMessage array ?

Comment: @user5313398 use `ByteBuffer` for that. Read the javadocs for `ByteBuffer` but mainly with  `ByteBuffer#put(byte[])` and other `ByteBuffer#put` methods family

Comment: I tried this byte[] fullMessage=byteBuffer.toArray();
              
              fullMessage.put(messageID); and got error on the method put

Comment: You are supposed to put everyhing into byteBuffer first, and make it an array as a last step. Read the documentation.

Comment: ok I managed it ready now first I declare like this ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(12+bodyLen);

Comment: I am not sure how to push the messageID, bodyLen byte into the buf cause I have already read them as integer rite

Comment: I am doing this ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(12+bodyLen);
              buf.put(messageID);
              buf.put(bodyLen);
              buf.put(phoneNum);
              buf.put(serialNum);
              buf.put(messageBody);
              is this correct?

Comment: yep, you can use `putInt` as well etc. Check the documentation https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html

Comment: I did this  buf.put((byte)messageID); is that acceptable ?

Comment: I tried this finally error: cannot find symbol
              byte[] fullMessage=buf.toArray();
                                    ^
  symbol:   method toArray()

Comment: Its `buf.array()`. Mate why cant you read the docs? You are that lazy?

Comment: I tried this byte[] fullMessage=buf.array();
              
              
              for(int sf=0,s=fullMessage.length;sf<s;sf++){
               
               System.out.println("\n\nprint value for : "+sf+"  "+"value is:"+(byte)fullMessage[sf]);
                  // do your XOR operations -> xor operator is ^
              } but I end up printing integer value rather than the byte cause some of it integer. Even thought I remove (byte) its still the same

Comment: You need to ask another question i guess as nobody will read that mess you have pasted here.